# What knowledge is required for understanding the AlphaZero paper?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, alphazero, sutton-barto

My goal is to understand AlphaZero paper published by deepmind. I'm beginning my journey trying to get the basic intuition of reinforcement learning from the [book](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf) by Barto and Sutton.

As per my background, I'm familiar with MDPs, value iteration and policy iteration.

I wanted to ask until what chapter of Barto and Sutton's book is one required to read in order to fully comprehend AlphaZero's paper. Monte-Carlo Tree Search is discussed in Chapter-8 of the book. Will it be enough till that? Or would I be needing more resources apart from this book?

Comment: Start reading the paper and look up the things that you don't understand or ask a question about it.

Comment: After completing the relevant chapter of the book, I would suggest you take a look at the cited references in the paper (especially those parts that you feel you need more materials).

Comment: @Brale yes, this worked for me with GPT-2... however, the tree of unknowns is quite deep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more you read, the more deeply you can understand any paper, but given your stated background, reading the Monte-Carlo Tree Search chapter of Barto & Sutton, plus Gerald Tesauro's [TD-Gammon paper](https://cling.csd.uwo.ca/cs346a/extra/tdgammon.pdf) (which is pretty accessible, and which is the basis for the *other* technique used in AlphaZero) should be enough to get a pretty good idea of what they did.